# Can Java BufferedWriter autosize columns before writing and write colored rows?

Tags: java

Currently, I have a method that writes out CSV files from a list of models:

```java
File file = null;
Writer rw = null;
BufferedWriter bw = null;

try {
    file = new File(outPath + filename);
    rw = new FileWriter(reportFile);
    bw = new BufferedWriter(reportWriter);

    bw.write("HeaderCell1,HeaderCell2");
    
    for (Model model : models) {
        String line = quote(String.valueOf(modelclass.getField1())) + ",";
        line += quote(String.valueOf(modelclass.getField2())) + ",";
        line += "/n";
        
        bw.write(line);
    }
    
    
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    if (bw != null) {
        try {
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error closing buffered writer", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String quotes(String toQuote) {
    return "\"" + outStr + "\"";
}
```

When this writes out, it looks like this in a CSV:

```
|Header1    |Header2    |
|-----------|-----------|
|field1Value|field2Value|
```

There is no formatting or anything or autosizing, and I was wondering if there are methods in BufferedWriter that allow you to color the cells "Header1" and "Header2" and to autosize them and center it? Or is that something outside of BufferedWriter

Comment: `BufferedWriter` can't do any of those things by itself: it literally just writes the chars it is given. You have to decide on widths and send the appropriate terminal control sequences for colors yourself.

Comment: Also: use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: @AndyTurner Do you have any recommendations for which java classes can do all this?

Answer (score 0):

A CSV is just a simple plain textfile, so there is no formatting for CSV-Files.
But there are APIs for writing Excel-Files.
[Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) is one of them.

Baeldung has also written about [Working with Microsoft Excel in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-microsoft-excel)
Besides Apache POI he mentions a JExcel API there.